# Why is {maxPixels : } set to 1024 for MODIS and 80 for Landsat?

Tags: google-earth-engine, modis, landsat

I am currently trying to understand how images are resampled and reprojected in google earth engine and I came across this tutorial: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/resample

Why is maxPixels:1024 and maxPixels:80 for MODIS and Landsat respectively? I searched specifications but did not find this information.

Comment: I don't see anything that defines Landsat's maxPixels as 80. The only instance of "80" in that tutorial refers to the visualization parameters, which allows the user to define what value gets mapped to 255. maxPixels defines the number of pixels that can go into the reducer as per this source: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/reducers_reduce_region

Comment: What about 1024 for MODIS then?

Comment: So is the instance of '1024' merely an artifact of visualization alone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`maxPixels` in `reduceResolution` refers to:

> The maximum number of input pixels to combine for each output pixel. Setting this too large will cause out-of-memory problems.

see: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#eeimagereduceresolution

It is an upper limit for the pixels to include for resampling and not a fixed amount of pixels to be used.